# How to merge webm video with mp4 video with transperency?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 1080p webm video and 500x300 mp4 video. How could I place muted mp4 video on top-center position of webm video with transparency? The output file format needed ".webm". Here what similar code I found, but it uses two mp4 videos and second video scales full width on front of first one:
    `ffmpeg \
        -i in1.mp4 -i in2.mp4 \
        -filter_complex " \
            [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x360[top]; \
            [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x360, \
                 format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]; \
            [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1" \
        -vcodec libx264 out.mp4`

Output log:
[image: Output log:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg \
        -i in1.webm -i in2.mp4 \
        -filter_complex " \
            [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[base]; \
            [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, \
                 format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[overlay]; \
            [base][overlay]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=0[v]"
        -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -shortest out.webm
```

The output file won't have the input webm's transparency but it can be done if required.

Comment: Thank you, but It writes error - "Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1. [libopus @ 0x7f86ba818c00] No bit rate set. Defaulting to 96000 bps. [libopus @ 0x7f86ba818c00] 1 frames left in the queue on closing. Conversion failed!"

Comment: It has the same error - "Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.". I've attached output log in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, everything works well, the webm file was corrupted that's why I think it throws that error. Could you tell is there any chances to speed up conversation? For example, if I will have two webm files, would it faster, rather than one webm and one mp4 file? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The slow speed here is due to the VP9 encoding, not the input files. Add `-threads 4` to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, found using parameter "-lossless 1" makes no quality loss and using "-threads 4" with "-c:v libvpx-vp9 -quality realtime -speed 8 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1" much more faster.